# how to solve the slow loading of an Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I am building an app using Laravel Vue. And now I am working on PWA(Progressive Web Apps). I noticed when I add a manifest.json file, **the google chrome starts to load slowly my application**. **And not only slow, sometimes it doesn't load the dynamic data as well.**  **Here is my manifest.json file**

```
{
  "name": "InfixEdu",
  "short_name": "LMS",
  "start_url": "/home",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#FFE9D2",
  "theme_color": "#FFE1C4",
  "orientation": "portrait-primary",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/uploads/website/logo/icon-72x72.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "72x72"
    },
    {
      "src": "/uploads/website/logo/icon-96x96.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
      "src": "/uploads/website/logo/icon-128x128.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "/uploads/website/logo/icon-144x144.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "144x144"
    },
    {
      "src": "/uploads/website/logo/icon-152x152.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "152x152"
    },
    {
      "src": "/uploads/website/logo/icon-192x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/uploads/website/logo/icon-384x384.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "384x384"
    },
    {
      "src": "/uploads/website/logo/icon-512x512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ]
}
```

If anyone can help regarding this help it will be very helpful

Comment: Does this affect e.g. Internet explorer too?

Comment: i didnt try on internet explorer but on internet edge it doesnt effect

Comment: And what loads slowly? Do scripts and stylesheets take longer to load? Does the page itself take longer to download?

Comment: may be the scripts and stylesheets???

Comment: Don't guess, open the network tab under the dev tools (F12) and compare load times with and without the manifest